# How does one automatically lint Coq files in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, coq, vscoq

I installed a coq linter in vscode but I get this issue:

```
Cannot lint the coq file.
```

[image]

I am using this extension.

Why is it not linting my file?

---

cross: https://github.com/fpoli/vscode-coq-linter/issues/1

Comment: what about this linter: https://github.com/fpoli/vscode-coq-linter why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Coq has no linter, the usual extension for it is [vscoq](https://github.com/coq-community/vscoq)

Comment: what about this: https://github.com/fpoli/vscode-coq-linter ?

Comment: it only runs coqc on the file. You are better off with vscoq.